# How to handle parse JSON errors in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift and though I've read responses to many questions with a similar title, since there are apparently so many ways to handle HTTP calls in Swift, I'm completely confused.

I use `URLSession.shared.dataTask` to make HTTP calls to [an open API](https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest) and handle the response as

```
let fiatRates = try! JSONDecoder().decode(FiatResponse.self, from: data!)
                
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  completion(fiatRates)
}
```

where `FiatResponse` is

```
struct FiatResponse: Decodable {
    var rates: [String: Float]
    var base: String
    var date: String
}
```

When I wrap this is `do-catch`, I get this warning:

> Catch block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in do block

Yet the app crashes with an error in the `do` block in case the API returns errors or times out. In. such situation the app never runs the `catch` block.

How can I tweak my code to correctly parse the JSON response and run the `catch` block, should an error occur?

Comment: Where did you put your `try`/`catch` exactly?

Comment: You are using `try!` which ignores any thrown errors so remove the ! to properly handle any errors with a do/catch

Comment: That was it @JoakimDanielson Thank you. I didn't understand the meaning of ! in the first place.

Comment: Why this is closed? It's rookie, but doesn't seem off-topic to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `!` to `try` the error will not be thrown, instead it will crash the app. To make the `do-catch` work you need to get rid of the `!`:

```swift
do {
    let fiatRates = try JSONDecoder().decode(FiatResponse.self, from: data!)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can read more about it here, in [this blogpost](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/8/optional-try). Also, [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) is the full documentation.